# Modifying static variable from child class global context

Tags: java, inheritance, static

Hi im trying to create a class with static functionality. I have and abstract class with the static methods that calls member functions depending on the implementation. Something like this:

```
public abstract class Input {
    
    protected static Input instance;
    
    public static boolean isKeyPressed(int keycode) {
        return instance.isKeyPressedImpl(keycode);
    }

    protected abstract boolean isKeyPressedImpl(int keycode);
}
```

And then have child classes for each platform implementing the abstract methods. My problem is that i want the Input class to be static so you dont have to ever instanciate it outside. So from a child class i wanted to do something like this:

```
public class WindowsInput extends Input {
    
    static {
        Input.instance = new WindowsInput();
    }
    
    @Override
    protected boolean isKeyPressedImpl(int keycode) {
        long window = Application.get().getWindow().getPointer();
        int state = glfwGetKey(window, keycode);
        return state == GLFW_PRESS || state == GLFW_REPEAT;
    }
}
```

Modifying the value of the static instance to be from this particular class. But the static snippet from above is never executed.
Is there a functioning or better way to get the expected result i want?
Thank you in advanced.

Comment: not sure i got you but to define class static you can do that only if it innerclass
"My problem is that i want the Input class to be static so you dont have to ever instanciate it outside"
https://dev.java/learn/nested-classes/
what you mean with outside you mean to restrict input to be only extended by certain classes if yes they use sealed
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/language/sealed-classes-and-interfaces.html

Comment: What happens if you have more than one Input subclasses?  Who get to initlaize Instance.instance?  As for your problem, you need to make sure the class WindowsInput is loaded.  The static block of code is only executed when the class is loaded.  You can add a static method ensureLoaded() to WindowsInput and call it in your main class to ensure that the classes you needed are loaded.

Comment: the static initializer is run when the class is initialized ([8.7. Static Initializers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se18/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.7)), so you must reference the class in some way (e.g. `Class.forName( ... )`  or `WindowsInput.class`) to have it loaded and the initializer executed..... or you may use the Service Provider Interface - see the [`ServieLoader` class](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ServiceLoader.html)

Comment: @user16320675 I think you may consider posting that as an answer.